# Footnotes use line-spacing of main text in Memoir when \paragraphfootnotes is used

Tags: footnotes, memoir, line-spacing

Using the memoir class, many of my documents require double-spacing of the main text and single-spacing of footnotes. All is normally well, but when I use the `\paragraphfootnotes` command, the footnotes cease to be single-spaced and appear to take the double-spacing of the main text.

Here's an MWE; comment out the `\paragraphfootnotes` command to see the difference it makes in the line-spacing of the footnotes.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\paragraphfootnotes
\begin{document}
\DoubleSpacing
This is a memoir document.\footnote{Memoir.}
Blah blah blah blah blah.\footnote{This is a multiline footnote. 
Under normal circumstances, it will be single-spaced, 
despite the double-spacing of the main text. 
However, when the paragraphfootnotes command is given, 
it is double-spaced, seemingly using the line-spacing of the main text.}
Blah blah blah blah blah.\footnote{Blah.}
Blah blah blah blah blah.
Blah blah blah blah blah.
\end{document}
```

So, is there a fix for this, so that the footnotes remain single-spaced? I note a similar issue in the article class that is observed [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/384581/unintended-effects-of-a-solution-to-arranging-footnotes), but hopefully there is an easier method in memoir.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: You can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/863) as I did in my edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Double spacing is for typewriters, not typesetters.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\paragraphfootnotes
\begin{document}
%\DoubleSpacing
\baselineskip=2\baselineskip
This is a memoir document.\footnote{Memoir.}
Blah blah blah blah blah.\footnote{This is a multiline footnote. 
Under normal circumstances, it will be single-spaced, 
despite the double-spacing of the main text. 
However, when the paragraphfootnotes command is given, 
it is double-spaced, seemingly using the line-spacing of the main text.}
Blah blah blah blah blah.\footnote{Blah.}
Blah blah blah blah blah.
Blah blah blah blah blah.
\end{document}
```

Comment: True. But many court rules still require double spacing.  This worked.